# Questions Regarding with Regard to Closing a Forked Repository; Questions Regarding Accessing Git Bash

Tags: git, github

I have been looking up how to clone a forked repository on GitHub and have been following this guide: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo#cloning-your-forked-repository. However, I am a little bit confused about Step 4: Open Git Bash. How do you access Git Bash, and where can you find this feature on Git Hub? I tried looking it up but not find anything about it. Any input regarding this would be much appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: GitBash is a port of the Unix-ish bash CLI to Windows. If you don't have Windows, you probably already have bash. If you have WSL, you already have bash. Note that GitBash has nothing to do with Git itself, except for the fact that Git needs a POSIX-compatible shell, so Windows Git provides bash-ported-to-Windows and calls that "GitBash".

Comment: @torek "Git needs a POSIX-compatible shell" may be too strongly worded. It need bash to run hooks but normal Git commands work fine in cmd.

Comment: @NO_NAME: There are still some commands that haven't been rewritten fully in C (or at least, were as of the time Git-Bash was adapted, I'm not sure if the last ones are done now with the git-submodule rewrites).